# Xamarin.Forms.Shell: is it possible to use a custom NavigationPage with Shell?

Tags: xaml, navigationbar, custom-renderer, translucency, xamarin.forms.shell

I work on a **Xamarin.Forms.Shell** app containing 4 tabs.

On the **main tab**, I have:

- a `NavigationBar` through a `TitleView` containing a **logo**
- a `ScrollView` containing an `Image` as **background's header**
- a `ScrollView` containing the **main content**, that can cover the Header to be fully visible

The **XAML** looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="AvilaShellAppSample.Views.HomePage"
            Shell.NavBarHasShadow="False"
            Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True"
            x:Name="homePage">
    <!-- TitleView -->
    <Shell.TitleView >
        <Grid>
            <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage Source="resource://ShellAppSample.Resources.blackLogoTitle.svg"
                                            DownsampleHeight="6"
                                            HeightRequest="45"/>
        </Grid>
    </Shell.TitleView>
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:HomeViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid RowSpacing="0"
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray-050}"
            Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <!--  Header ScrollView : Image  -->
                <ScrollView>
                    <ContentView x:Name="headerView"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <!--  Header Image  -->
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="headerImage"
                                            Grid.Row="0"
                                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                                            BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Gray-200}"
                                            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                                            HeightRequest="280"
                                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                                            Source="resource://ShellAppSample.Resources.indoor.jpg">
                            </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                        </Grid>
                    </ContentView>
                </ScrollView>

                <!--  Content ScrollView  -->
                <ScrollView>
                <ctrl:ParallaxScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        ParallaxHeaderView="{x:Reference headerView}"
                                        LogoHeaderView="{x:Reference logoHeaderView}"
                                        HiddenView="{x:Reference hiddenView}"
                                        MainPage="{Binding homePage}">
                    <Grid ColumnSpacing="0"
                        RowSpacing="0"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="220" /> 
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!-- Content -->
                    </Grid>
                </ctrl:ParallaxScrollView>
                </ScrollView>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Like this, it's working fine.

But I would like:

- to **hide** the `NavigationBar` **by default**, and to display it only after the user has started to scroll the main content
- that the `Image` of the background's header fills all the space from the top screen: so the `StatusBar` should be be displayed in transparency over this Image

I've changed the **XAML** to hide the `NavigationBar` and to display the Header at the top of the screen through a negative `Margin`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            ...
            Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True"
            x:Name="homePage">
    <!-- TitleView -->
    <Shell.TitleView >
        ...
    </Shell.TitleView>
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:HomeViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid RowSpacing="0"
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray-050}"
            Margin="0,-20,0,0">
```

***=> This works well on iOS, but not quite on Android as the `StatusBar` is not transparent.***

Finally, to display the `NavigationBar` after a scroll, I use a `ParallaxScrollView` control that get some references of this View.

I do something like this:

```
if (y <= -60)
{
    Shell.SetNavBarIsVisible(MainPage, true);
    Shell.SetNavBarHasShadow(MainPage, true);
    Shell.SetPresentationMode(MainPage, PresentationMode.Animated);
    }
}
else
{
    Shell.SetNavBarIsVisible(MainPage, false);
    Shell.SetNavBarHasShadow(MainPage, false);
    Shell.SetPresentationMode(MainPage, PresentationMode.Animated);
}
```

***=> on iOS, the display of the `NavigationBar` is well done, but there is remaning gap before the header when the `NavigationBar` is hidden again. On Android, the rendering is satisfactory.***

Here is the [rendering](https://i.ibb.co/bLPC9yp/ezgif-1-c576a99acd47.gif) on iOS.

***It seems it's not possible de create a Custom `NavigationPage` for the main page of a Xamarin.Forms.Shell app. So is there a way to achieve the expected behavior?***